# Is there a way to add a card to google / apple wallet from a Flutter application?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-pay

Is there a method to add a card to Google Wallet or Apple Wallet directly from a Flutter application without resorting to platform-specific code?

Comment: There will need to be platform specific code somewhere. You can search pub.dev for a plug-in, but if you can’t find one then you will need to write it yourself

Comment: Yes, no luck on this research yet. at least i have not found any trustworthy publishers or publishers with active maintainers.